# Text equivalent of CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol

Tags: c#, internationalization

Is there a text equivalent of CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol provided as a property in C#.

e.g. CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol would give me $ but I want something textual like USD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use this:

```
var name = System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.ISOCurrencySymbol;
```

If you need the currency symbol for a specific region, you would use the `RegionInfo`'s constructor to specify a culture. For example, to always use en-US:

```
var name = new System.Globalization.RegionInfo(1033).ISOCurrencySymbol;
```

or

```
var name = new System.Globalization.RegionInfo("en-US").ISOCurrencySymbol;
```

Take a look at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.isocurrencysymbol) for more information.

Comment: @AJM - Your edit is basically the same as the first example, `System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.ISOCurrencySymbol;`. There's no need to pass in the current culture as that is what `CurrentRegion` does.